# The checkbox on django web page is turned in to checked=true when i post the form

Tags: django, forms

I have Django 1.9.5 web project.
I have a page and a form on it.
In the form there is a checkbox that is not Cehecked.

In the model :

> delete_student = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_("DELETE This Student"))

When i save and post this form the page comes back with same form values.
But this time the checkbox is checked. I don't want it to be checked without
somebody clicks it.

The checkbox should remain unchecked unless somebody clicks it.

student_form.cleaned_data.get("delete_student") should come False as its default vaule is False and nobody clicks it.

Form is :

```
    class MineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=False)
    re_password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput, label='Re-type Password', required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Mine
        exclude = []
        widgets = {
            'gender': forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer),
            'address': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 3}),
            'uuid': forms.HiddenInput(),
        }
        exclude = ['user',]
```

Comment: can i show your form..??

Comment: added form to main post

Comment: Can you clarify "When i save and post this form the page comes back with same form values. But this time the checkbox is checked."? It's not clear what are you meaning.